# Are all side-effects of executor tasks visible after invokeAll?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, memory-model

If I submit some tasks to an `Executor` using `invokeAll`, am I guaranteed that the submitted thread sees all the side effects of the task executions, even if I don't call `get()` on each of the returned `Future`s?

From a practical point of view, it would seem that this would be a useful guarantee, but I don't see anything in the javadoc.

More precisely, do all actions in the body of a `Callable` submitted to an executor *happen-before* the return from the `invokeAll()` call?

It's annoying to uselessly call `get()` on each future, when in fact the return type is `Void` and no exceptions are thrown - all the work in the happens as side-effects.

Comment: For future wandering readers I just wanted to add something which helped me understand this a bit better. The official oracle docs on happens-before relationships in the JVM are here under 'Memory Consistency Properties': https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html under the section titled 'Memory Consistency Properties'. This also makes reference to ExecutorService, Callable and Future and their happens-before relationships. Thanks for asking this question. It helped answer mine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `invokeAny()` promises that no tasks are still in execution when `invokeAny()` returns, this will be the case: all side effects are visible.

In order for `invokeAny()` to know that all tasks are done, it needs to have synchronized with those threads, meaning that the returning of the functions happens after the tasks completing (and everything that happens in the task). However the API of 'ExecutorSerive' and 'Future.cancel()' does not explicitly say what happens when you cancel a running task (in particular: will `cancel()` wait with returning until the tasks has stopped running. The fact that after calling `cancel()`, `isDone()` must return true, does imply that `cancel()` will not return until the task has actually finished executing.

One more thing to watch out for is that you will not know if a task ever started execution, when using `invokeAny()`  without inspecting the `Future` objects.

Comment: The OP asked about `invokeAll()`, not `invokeAny()`

Comment: Yes, sorry - I had inconsistently used both `invokeAny()` and `invokeAll()` in my original question and I fixed this later.

In any case, I tend to agree that for in order for `invokeAll()` to know that all tasks are done, it must synchronize with each thread, and this will probably set up happens-before with all earlier thread actions.

You could still imagine a kind of 'lazy' implementation that defers some synchronization to the `Future.get()` call, but the wording "returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete" seems to rule  that out.  Accepted!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

> Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable
>   task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that
>   task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via
>   Future.get().

As I read this, there is a memory barrier on task submission, so *potentially* you'd need to call `get()` on the last task in your list to, but not the others.

*However*, since calling `get()` is the only way to determine whether the task completed or threw, I would still call it on every `Future`, regardless of memory guarantees.

Comment: Well in this case you can assume that my Callable cannot throw.

I don't think there is a valid concept of "last" task, since although you submit the tasks in some order, and you get the `Futures` back in the same order, their _finishing_ order is not defined since some tasks may of course run longer than others.